# Google Maps Reviews Integration

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-reviews

How to configure our project on google console to grant accesss on our business profile to use the API to get reviews and reply on it.

After I created the project, I enabled **Google My Business API** Library and other libraries that were required from the documentation. Then, I created OAuth credentials and I added the URL link **https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground** to the Authorized Redirect URLs. When I try to fetch my account, my accounts from this API **https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/** it shows me that my acount is personal. When I try to fetch the locations from the response account ID from this API **[https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/locations)** it shows that it is not found.Furthermore, there is an issue with the quota's limitation. I am unable to increase the quotas.

Answer (score 1):

The Google My Business API is private by default.

Use this form to request quota:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSenhlfSv_Gms-g5wtqcXHbGEXzI_08140cWwwSAtqtoUnm1ig/viewform